# Option to simplify this bitbucket pipeline

Tags: automation, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I created a bitbucket pipeline, but for every script i need to execute the same scripts:

```
- apt-get update
- apt-get -qq install git-ftp
```

But i am looking for a way to optimise and simplify this:

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git
pipelines:
    custom: # Pipelines that are triggered manually via the Bitbucket GUI
        init-staging:
            - step:
                script:
                    - apt-get update
                    - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
                    - git ftp init --user "$FTP_USERNAME" --passwd "$FTP_PASSWORD" "$STAGING_FTP_URL" -v
        init-production:
            - step:
                script:
                    - apt-get update
                    - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
                    - git ftp init --user "$FTP_USERNAME" --passwd "$FTP_PASSWORD" "$PRODUCTION_FTP_URL" -v
        re-deploy-all-to-staging: # -- Deploys all files from the selected commit
            - step:
                script:
                    - apt-get update
                    - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
                    - git ftp init --user "$FTP_USERNAME" --passwd "$FTP_PASSWORD" "$STAGING_FTP_URL" -v --all
        re-deploy-all-to-production: # -- Deploys all files from the selected commit
            - step:
                script:
                    - apt-get update
                    - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
                    - git ftp init --user "$FTP_USERNAME" --passwd "$FTP_PASSWORD" "$PRODUCTION_FTP_URL" -v --all
        manual-to-staging:
            - step:
                script:
                    - apt-get update
                    - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
                    - git ftp push --user "$FTP_USERNAME" --passwd "$FTP_PASSWORD" "$STAGING_FTP_URL" -v
        manual-to-production:
            - step:
                script:
                    - apt-get update
                    - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
                    - git ftp push --user "$FTP_USERNAME" --passwd "$FTP_PASSWORD" "$PRODUCTION_FTP_URL" -v
    branches: # Automated triggers on commits to branches
        master: # When committing to master branch
            - step:
                deployment: staging
                script:
                    - apt-get update
                    - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
                    - git ftp push --user "$FTP_USERNAME" --passwd "$FTP_PASSWORD" "$STAGING_FTP_URL" -v
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different Docker image. The one you are currently using (`samueldebruyn/debian-git`) doesn't include git-ftp, but if you use one that somebody else has made (check hub.docker.com) or make one yourself then you'll have that utility at the start of the pipeline. That will save you steps in the pipeline, and also build minutes.

Comment: I am the creator of the debian-git image and I would not recommend using it anymore. At the time I created it, there weren't a lot of alternatives. I don't have the time to maintain such an image, so `bitname/git` or `alpine/git` are great alternatives.